# error TS2339: Property 'access_token' does not exist angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This question may be asked earlier. But they did not help me to resolve my issue. Below is my service file.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/core';
import { AppSettings } from '../app.settings';
import { Ticket } from '../_models/index';

@Injectable()
export class TicketService {
    options= new RequestOptions();
    public access_token:string;
    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private cookieService: CookieService
    ) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        let userInfo = this.cookieService.getObject('userInfo');
        if(userInfo){
            //this.access_token = (userInfo.access_token)?userInfo.access_token:'';
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I am getting access_token from cookie to authenticate a user and dumping it into an access_token variable. It is working fine if a user is already logged in. But first time when `npm start` execute, it generates an error **error TS2339: Property 'access_token' does not exist**. So explicitly need to comment **this.access_token = (userInfo.access_token)?userInfo.access_token:'';** this line and then after npm start works. I have also defined variable initially. But still, it generates an error. I am not getting where I am doing wrong. Please guide if you have faced the same issue and resolved it.

Comment: Did you try initializing the variable? I think TypeScript excludes it otherwise in generated JS: `public access_token:string = '';`

Comment: Not true. It is only stripped down by TS or minification if there is no reference to that property anywhere in the code.

Comment: Did you also try marking `userInfo` as type `any`? `let userInfo: any = this.cookieService.getObject('userInfo');`

Comment: Rather than ``any``, I would define it as ``{ access_token: string }``. The problem is that you have to do it everywhere. If you define it on the method level, the type is inferred when assigned to a variable. Thus it only needs to be defined once not in every place.

Comment: @Arg0n, Yes `let userInfo: any` worked for me. Thank you

Comment: @MaheshTechcompose No problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score -1):

Just change this line:

```
let userInfo = this.cookieService.getObject('userInfo');
```

To this (`: any`):

```
let userInfo: any = this.cookieService.getObject('userInfo');
```

In order to let TypeScript know the returned value could be/contain anything.

Comment: A `CookieService` is a good example of when it's OK to use `any` for the returned value. Especially since he (in this case) only use it to set a variable  which has a defined type (`access_token: string`). And yes, I realized that it was during transpilation the error occurred. Which is also why i removed that comment pretty long ago.

Comment: It's more handy to have a general function to fetch cookies instead of having to write a new function for each. It also makes it reusable in other applications without modification.